# INA219 to measure AND supply to a RPi3

Tags: pi-3, gpio

I have seen a lot of topics regarding using the INA 2019 sensor combined with Arduino, or to measure the voltage of a battery that powers something else. However, I want to sense the battery that is powering the pi itself.

My setup consists of: 12V battery <--> step down converter (5V) <--> RPi3 (via gpio or usb, both work)

It works fine without the INA 219. When I setup like this: 12V battery <--> step down converter (5V) <--> INA219 <--> RPi3

It does not power the Pi, no lights, nothing.

What I managed to do is, since the step-down converter has 2 usb outputs:

12V battery <--> step down converter (5V) <--> INA219  RPi3

This means, from INA219, I plug the Vin to the Pi (gpio). From the converter, I plug it to the Pi as well (usb port).

(Sorry for my clumsy explanation, this is the first time asking about electronics, not sure how to draw it better)

Is there any problem having this setup? I feel like something might break down. If this is not ok, how can I proceed? I don't think the INA is broken since it outputs to the pin when I use the last setup.

Comment: I am a little confused.  I thought that device was a shunt which needs to be placed in parallel with the current flow, only a milliamp or so will flow through the device itself (the Pi needs a thousand milliamps or so).

Comment: @joan I wasfollowing this tutorial, doesn't look like it's in parallel: https://www.rototron.info/raspberry-pi-ina219-tutorial/

Comment: Still having a problem? If you sketch it out I might see where you are getting lost. (I have INA219 working with 12v stepdown power supplies on my Pis)

Comment: Turned out I had a faulty INA219, it's working now (I also changed the design to work with 4xAA batteries instead of the stepdown converter).